# 70s or 80s TV show, possibly post-apocalyptic with a massive train-like car

Tags: story-identification, tv

I seem to remember the intro to the show having the train-car traveling amongst some barren mountainous terrain.  I seem to remember that each section of the car-train had a different purpose, like the medical car, and the weapons car, etc.

I don't think it ran for more than a season, possibly not even completing a full season. It was live-action. It was on US television, and I don't remember any accents, so I am guessing it was American.

Comment: I remember exactly that TV Show and still looking for it. The Train was actually composed of a pickup truck that connected to the trailer and could be removed to use just as a normal vehicle. Think the main character was someone like Dolph Lundgren and i believe he was from the future and used to hide the trailer so no one could see it (kinda in a back to the future way..) any suggestions on what this could be? Any help would be much appreciated, definitely not Ark II or other suggestions here...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## [*Ark II*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ark_II)

[image: The Ark II vehicle stands on a barren landscape: it is a long wide white vehicle with 6 wheels; it has a pointed front but is pretty rectangular]

Here's a guess: [**Ark II**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0127989/)

> Three young scientists travel around the country in the 25th century after the world has been ravaged by pollution. In their hi-tech RV, the titular Ark II, they study the land and help out those in need.

[image: Diagram of the Ark II on a white and orange background; it shows 3 different angles and its size in comparison to a human (just a bit taller)]

Go [here](http://space1970.blogspot.com/2010/12/re-post-ark-ii-1976.html) and [here](http://reflectionsonfilmandtelevision.blogspot.com/search/label/Ark%20II) for more details, episode guides and pics. Watch a making-of documentary [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kZxCTx6y198).

Comment: I'm thinking yours is the correct answer... the asker mentioned jumpsuits. Good answer.

Comment: @John - Actually, "The Highwayman" was my first pick :-) But with the additional info, yeah, "Ark II" might be the one. Have my doubts though. I mean, how does one forget a _talking chimpanzee_?

Comment: This was a punishingly bad show.

Comment: I've seen worse shows.  But, you know, I totally forgot there wasva monkey in this one.

Answer (score 10):

Yet another possibility:

[image: Terrahawks Overlander: a model of the vehicle stands on a desert landcape; it is silver with blue stripes and made of 3 sections each with 6 wheels]

This is the Overlander from [*Terrahawks*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrahawks). It's function is:

> an automated all-terrain vehicle similar to a rail-free train with multiple, articulated sections that brings supplies to Hawknest. - ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrahawks#Other_vehicles))

This image is from [David Sisson's page](http://www.davidsissonmodels.co.uk/overlander.htm) - a man who restored the original model.

In your question, you mention **multiple sections**, which the Overlander had. And you mention **mountainous terrain** - which was exactly the terrain on which the Overlander drove.

See if the vehicle in this video looks familiar:

Answer (score 8):

This is almost certainly [*The Highwayman*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Highwayman_(TV_series)). It was another cheesy Glen Larson series from the late 1980s or so, and depicted two quasi-law enforcement officers who drove trailer trucks that (I kid you not) could convert into helicopters. One of them had this ridiculous Australian accent, but I am uncertain if this was just acting or if he was someone famous from that continent or whatever.

I don't think it lasted a full season.

Here is an image I dug up on Google to confirm it:

[image: a large silver truck stands on a desert area; it has ten wheels; the trailer is typical of a truck but with a shark fin in the middle; the front looks like a bunch of thrusters from a space shape]

Comment: It was live-action.  It was on US television, and I don't remember any accents, so I am guessing it was American.

I've been googling for a while now, and the closest thing I came up with is the "Mammoth Car" from Speed Racer.  It was very much like that, except not animated.  

At least I think that's what I remember.  

I saw "The Highwayman" in my Google searches, and I don't think that's what it was.

This is driving me nuts.  Making me question my sanity and my memory. LOL!

Comment: It was only the one actor with the accent... like I said, it was a Larson show (Battlestar, Knight Rider). This is it. Go watch one and you'll be convinced.

Comment: Oh snap, I remember that show!  Well I never watched it but I recall it being made fun of somewhere along with Manimal (which I've also never seen... man, maybe I should watch those shows).

Comment: @22ndCenturyFza This was about on the level of Manimal... even as a 13 yr old it seemed kind of stupid. A science-fiction-starved 13 yr old.

Comment: @John O - Hahaha, I feel rather science-fiction-starved today.  I thought Geek was the new Gay but the only American SF show on these days that I like, Almost Human, is going to be canceled... If what I heard is to be believed -huff-

Comment: Maybe it was just so bad that either it never existed on the internet, or all traces of it have been completely eliminated so that old farts like me will begin to question whether or not it was real.  *sigh*

Comment: @David http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1duAXF8bNAk

Comment: Yeah. I'm pretty sure that's not it.  I seem to remember the occupants of the "mammoth car" were a crew, not a single guy.  And they were less "Mad Max" and more futuristic jump-suit kinda garments.  *shrug*  Regardless, thanks for the link. :)

Comment: @David - it will really help if you add these details you mention here to your question - I missed this when adding my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Could you be thinking of [*Damnation Alley*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075909/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_19)? Although produced and released as a theatrical movie, it made its way to TV fairly quickly. IIRC, the TV version was broadcast in two parts, making it feel like a mini-series.

Practically another star of the show, the "Landmaster" was a custom-built articulated vehicle with a very unique wheel arrangement - the three-wheel clusters could rotate to climb over large obstacles. The Landmaster was actually built full-scale and driveable, having a working drivetrain.

[image: A chunky silver vehicle stands in a barren landscape; a man pokes his head through a top hatch and there is a missile launcher mounted on the back. The wheels are made up of groups of 3 in a triangle]

As for the "specialized sections", could you be thinking of the movie *[The Core](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0298814/?ref_=nv_sr_1)*?

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like *Genesis II* and/or [*Planet Earth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_Earth_(film)). These Gene Roddenberry TV movies involved a train system and the character name Dylan Hunt.

[image: Painting of an underground train system; passengers wait in an unmodified cave with a transparent tube in it and a train passing through]

Comment: The user has confirmed it is Ark II, but stay and have a look around at any other questions you might like to answer or ask any questions you might have about works of Science Fiction and Fantasy, also take a look at our [tour]

Answer (score 3):

I think you might have a few shows mixed up but I believe I have your answer. I believe that you are referring to the second season of *The Highwayman* where they added the actor [Mark Alexander "Jacko" Jackson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_%22Jacko%22_Jackson) who was a former Australian rules football player.

He had a different-styled (1/2-height) tractor that could separate, unlike the tractor that actor, Sam Jones drove that had a helicopter that separated. Here is a photo of Jacko's tractor-trailer:

[image: A low narrow car, black with a silver bottom pulls a low long truck trailer of similar design down a road]

Answer (score 0):

[*Supertrain*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supertrain).

> *Supertrain* is an American television drama/adventure series that ran on NBC from February 7 to May 5, 1979. Nine episodes were made, including a 2-hour pilot episode.

Comment: Hi there! Could you [edit] how you think that matches? Links tend to rot, so it's better to transcribe the relevant information