# Saturday morning TV show from the 1970's or 1980's with a silver RV driven around a desert

Tags: story-identification

What I remember about it was it was a group of people driving around a desert in a vehicle that looked like an RV that was silver in color.

I don't remember any of the actors in it.

It was a Saturday morning kids show and was live action. It was on one of the big 3 networks, I know this because we didn't have cable at the time.

Comment: While it certainly looks like a duplicate, we don't close Story-ID questions as dupes unless the asker confirms the answer is correct.

Comment: @SSumner it is confirmed by the user in the comments.

Comment: Please take the time to accept the answer.  People put effort into answers and they get a bonus if their answer is selected.

Comment: To those voting to close, note that the OP has accepted an answer that appears to be a sci-fi show.

Comment: @Blackwood Then it's a dupe...

Comment: It should not have been left open

Comment: @Edlothiad If you can provide a link to the dupe, I will happily VTC as that dupe.

Comment: SQB linked it [right there](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51230/70s-or-80s-tv-show-possibly-post-apocalyptic-with-a-massive-train-like-car)? Two years ago..?

Answer (score 26):

Is it Ark II? Four teenagers and an intelligent chimp drove around in a big vehicle (called the Ark, of course) dispensing technology to a post-apocalyptic world.

[image: The Ark]

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ark_II)

---

*The querant has accepted this answer in a comment:*

> yes that was it. – [user25116 Apr 16 '14 at 2:41](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54242/saturday-morning-tv-show-from-the-1970s-or-1980s-with-a-silver-rv-driven-aroun/161930#comment105182_54266)

Comment: yes that was it.

Comment: @user25116 - Don't forget to accept this answer. Just click on the check mark to the left of the post.

Comment: I watched this as a kid during its original run.  I remember lusting after Jonah's sweet jetpack.  I remember Jonah and Ruth and Samuel and the mini-rover and the non-lethal light thingy that stunned people.  Interestingly, I do not remember Adam (the chimp) at *all*.

Comment: “Four teenagers and an intelligent monkey” — hey, don’t be mean to NSYNC.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite and Greenstone Walker, this might be off topic and shows me to be an animal nerd, but chimps are not monkeys, they lack a tail and have opposable thumbs, making them apes.

Answer (score 1):

Damnation Alley had a vehicle like that as a survival transport to a sanctuary or some such if I remember correctly

Edit: Behold the "Landmaster"

[image]

Comment: Can you provide any other details that suggest a similarity?

Comment: Damnation Alley had a similar vehicle, but definitely wasn't a Saturday morning kid's show.