# Trying to ID a movie/or maybe TV show

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, post-apocalyptic

I believe it was sometime during the 70/80s I would have seen a movie/TV show with the following elements. I could be combining several shows/movies together. I am unsure.

1) There is a motor-home crossing a desert. I am under the impression it is a post apocalyptic desert and the occupants are attempting to survive.

2) These people - possibly the occupants of the motor-home find refuge among others. Then the group gets a attacked/or captured by some sort of beast like creature. They have to escape, their escape must go around a pit of lava/fire. They only have one set of glasses to protect their eyes and guy wears them and leads them around this pit and lava/fire to safety.

3) There is a cave. In a cave is a black shiny rock. Someone goes into the cave and gets all weird and shaky. I am under the impression the rock is from an alien world.

4) There is a guy traveling he comes to an edge of a swamp a great nasty beast arises and they make small talk and the beast - made of garbage (?) does not kill him.

Could be I am combining some movies/tv together. I was a child when I saw these shows, information gets rewritten and fuzzy when one ages.

Comment: Elements of this sound like [Neon City](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0104981/)

Comment: And the black rock reminds me of Evolution

Comment: Some of it reminds me of [Voyage to the Prehistoric Planet](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0059887/).

Comment: When you say motor home, do you mean an actual, literal, motor-home (something you'd see on the road now, like a  Winnebago), or something more futuristic? I'm thinking along the lines of [Ark 2](https://www.google.com/search?q=ark+2) or [Damnation Alley](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075909/reference), though it's clearly not the latter and I don't remember enough about the former to say.

Comment: I was under the vast memory impression it was a Winnebago, but that data could be flawed. I have watched Damnation Alley and that was not it. Currently I have been working on the Ark 2 episodes to see if one of them correlates. I will check out Voyage to the Prehistoric Planet, Evolution, and Neon City.

Comment: @phantom42 I was almost certain it was a Winnebago but it could be that motor home for Ark 2. We have been watching the Ark 2 shows in a attempt to possibly flush out at the episode that correlates. I have watched Damnation Alley and I have no memories of that movie. We will check out your recommendations of Neon City, Evolution, and Voyage to the Prehistoric Planet.

Comment: I think you meant for that to ping @Joelogon.

Comment: @Joelogon, you should post Damnation Alley as the other possible answer.

Comment: @jbjork, what's the difference between a Winnebago & a motor home?

Comment: @Richard Checked out Neon City and Evolution and they don't match up.

Comment: #Jim2B...I guess there is no difference between a Winnebago & a motor home.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51230/70s-or-80s-tv-show-possibly-post-apocalyptic-with-a-massive-train-like-car

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like multiple episodes of **Ark II**, an American TV series.  They made 15x 30 minute episodes in the late 1970s.  My best guess is the "Black Rock" best describes episode 5, **Omega**:

> The ARK encounters a community enslaved by a sentient super-computer
>   housed in a black monolith. Samuel succumbs to the computer's control,
>   jeopardizing Jonah's plan to deactivate it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ark_II

Picture of the Ark II
[image: Picture of the Ark II]

Could this be the "Black Rock"?
[image: Could this be the "Black Rock"?]

Comment: I have been suspicious for sometime that it was from Ark 2, we have been watching the episodes. I think we will skip directly to episode 5, Omega. Though the black rock was small, portable, I think it gave someone super powers or something or transported them. Ark II would also make sense as it was a kids show and I doubt my parents would let me watch any adult like scary sci-fi/post apocalyptic shows at the time.

Comment: I seem to recall another similar concept show with a different looking RV thingy.  They had a motorcycle too IIRC.

Comment: The other show I'm thinking of was probably Damnation Alley as mentioned above - the vehicle looks right.

Answer (score 2):

The other show from that era that featured a motor home (an actual Winnebago) was [Shazam!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shazam!_%28TV_series%29) (as with Ark 2, also a Filmation show), though it wasn't post-apocalyptic survival, more like superhero do-gooders roaming the land.

No idea if any of the plotlines match what you're looking for.

Here's the intro: