# Post-atomic movie featuring a "wasteland winnebago" vehicle?

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic

Many years ago I saw a movie that featured a very cool vehicle which was referred to as **"wasteland winnebago,"** I think. It vehicle didn't look like a winnebago at all. It looked more like a high-speed train or military airplane, with a flat pointy nose and a grey fuselage-shaped body, maybe 7-10 meters long. Its body had two  [articulated sections](http://www.texbrick.com/model_tractor/tractor3.jpg) and its big rubber wheels were arranged in triangles [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqB2W.jpg).

The movie could easily have been made in the 70s or early 80s. (I wonder if it might have been an episode of a series; I have no recollection of its length.) I think it plays out after a nuclear war; at least, the world seems completely deserted save for a few outposts, and the world is full of threats like elephant-sized scorpions.

I saw in a R/C hobby magazine once that somebody had built a scale replica of the vehicle. That might have been in the very late 80s, probably [RC Car Action](http://www.rccaraction.com/).

I'd love to know what that movie was!

Comment: Any chance this was the show "Ark II" with a similar setting? The details don't match, but you can see an image of the vehicle from the show at http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83016/trying-to-id-a-movie-or-maybe-tv-show/83106#83106

Comment: Sorry @Otis that's not it, although the hint #1 in that post is remarkably similar, as is [the vehicle](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Qks9y.jpg) - but it doesn't have those very special wheels nor the articulated sections (and it's not grey). My first thought was "yes" though...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Was it [Damnation Alley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damnation_Alley_%28film%29)?

Winnebago

Flat pointy nose.

Not articulated.

I vaguely recall they had a souped up motorcycle too.

Driving across wastelands

Wheels look like this:

Damnation Alley's Landmaster
[image: Damnation Alley's Landmaster]

Comment: @Torben Gundtofte-Bruun Trivia tidbit: the Landmaster went on to appear in [several other works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landmaster#Other_appearances), including a RP game called Morrowland Project, in which it appears as the [MARS One and has an articulated body](http://www.coldnorth.com/owen/game/miscellaney/morrow/mars-one.gif)

Comment: **BINGO!** Thank you so much for setting me straight! According to the [Landmaster page in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landmaster#Gallery) it was articulated, which isn't obvious from your image but [a bit clearer here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:2014-3-28-Landmaster-01.JPG). Yes, there was something about a motorcycle too but I don't remember it being anything special - but of course, with that kind of primary vehicle, how could the bike be normal!

Comment: The book by Roger Zelazny was so much better.  The "hero" in the book is very much a anti-hero, the last of the Hells Angels as I recall, rather than a group of military men in an armored vehicle in the film.

Comment: That also looks quite a bit like the old GIJoe personnel carrier toy.

Comment: And it starred Stringfellow Hawke from Airwolf!

Comment: @SystemDown ... Yah, Jan Michael Vincent ... This movie brings back some mems! I loved this movie when I was a kid, lol!

Comment: IMDB user review, don't you just love this: _"The only points I do give it, is for having the really cool looking landmaster vehicle ... Besides this, the film is a wreck unfortunately. ... a boring trek about a story that's not even being told."_ That's pretty accurate, sadly.